# Generating a file and writing to it in map function

Tags: java, hadoop

I am generating a csv file in my map function. So that each map task generates one csv file. Now this is a side effect and not the output of the mapper. The way I am naming those files is something like filename_inputkey. However when I run the application on a single node cluster, there is only one file generated. I have 10 lines in my input and as per my understanding goes, there will be 10 mapper tasks and 10 files would be generated. Let me know if I am thinking in a wrong way here.

Here is my GWASInputFormat class

```
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileSplit;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.RecordReader;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Reporter;

public class GWASInputFormat extends FileInputFormat<LongWritable, GWASGenotypeBean>{

@Override
public RecordReader<LongWritable, GWASGenotypeBean> getRecordReader(org.apache.hadoop.mapred.InputSplit input, JobConf job, Reporter arg2) throws IOException {
    return (RecordReader<LongWritable, GWASGenotypeBean>) new GWASRecordReader(job, (FileSplit)input);
}

}
```

Here is  GWASRecordReader

```
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileSplit;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LineRecordReader;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.RecordReader;

public class GWASRecordReader implements RecordReader<LongWritable, GWASGenotypeBean>{

private LineRecordReader lineReader;
private LongWritable lineKey;
private Text lineValue;

@Override
public void close() throws IOException {
    if(lineReader != null) {
        lineReader.close();
    }
}

public GWASRecordReader(JobConf job, FileSplit split) throws IOException {
    lineReader = new LineRecordReader(job, split);
    lineKey = lineReader.createKey();
    lineValue = lineReader.createValue();
}

@Override
public LongWritable createKey() {
    return new LongWritable();
}

@Override
public GWASGenotypeBean createValue() {
    return new GWASGenotypeBean();
}

@Override
public long getPos() throws IOException {
    return lineReader.getPos();
}

@Override
public boolean next(LongWritable key, GWASGenotypeBean value) throws IOException {
    if(!lineReader.next(lineKey, lineValue)){
        return false;
    }

    String[] values = lineValue.toString().split(",");

    if(values.length !=32) {
        throw new IOException("Invalid Record ");
    }

    value.setPROJECT_NAME(values[0]);
    value.setRESEARCH_CODE(values[1]);
    value.setFACILITY_CODE(values[2]);
    value.setPROJECT_CODE(values[3]);
    value.setINVESTIGATOR(values[4]);
    value.setPATIENT_NUMBER(values[5]);
    value.setSAMPLE_COLLECTION_DATE(values[6]);
    value.setGENE_NAME(values[7]);
    value.setDbSNP_RefSNP_ID(values[8]);
    value.setSNP_ID(values[9]);
    value.setALT_SNP_ID(values[10]);
    value.setSTRAND(values[11]);
    value.setASSAY_PLATFORM(values[12]);
    value.setSOFTWARE_NAME(values[13]);
    value.setSOFTWARE_VERSION_NUMBER(values[14]);
    value.setTEST_DATE(values[15]);
    value.setPLATE_POSITION(values[16]);
    value.setPLATE_ID(values[17]);
    value.setOPERATOR(values[18]);
    value.setGENOTYPE(values[19]);
    value.setGENOTYPE_QS1_NAME(values[20]);
    value.setGENOTYPE_QS2_NAME(values[21]);
    value.setGENOTYPE_QS3_NAME(values[22]);
    value.setGENOTYPE_QS4_NAME(values[23]);
    value.setGENOTYPE_QS5_NAME(values[24]);
    value.setGENOTYPE_QS1_RESULT(values[25]);
    value.setGENOTYPE_QS2_RESULT(values[26]);
    value.setGENOTYPE_QS3_RESULT(values[27]);
    value.setGENOTYPE_QS4_RESULT(values[28]);
    value.setGENOTYPE_QS5_RESULT(values[29]);
    value.setSTAGE(values[30]);
    value.setLAB(values[31]);
    return true;
}

@Override
public float getProgress() throws IOException {
    return lineReader.getProgress();
}

}
```

Mapper class

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.TreeMap;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataOutputStream;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapReduceBase;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.OutputCollector;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Reporter;

import com.google.common.base.Strings;

public class GWASMapper extends MapReduceBase implements Mapper<LongWritable, GWASGenotypeBean, Text, Text> {

private static Configuration conf;

@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
public void setup(org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.Context context) throws IOException {
    conf = context.getConfiguration();
    // Path[] otherFiles = DistributedCache.getLocalCacheFiles(context.getConfiguration());
}


@Override
public void map(LongWritable inputKey, GWASGenotypeBean inputValue, OutputCollector<Text, Text> output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException {



    checkForNulls(inputValue, inputKey.toString());




    output.collect(new Text(inputValue.getPROJECT_CODE()), new Text(inputValue.getFACILITY_CODE()));

}

private void checkForNulls(GWASGenotypeBean user, String inputKey) {

    String f1 = " does not have a value_fail";
    String p1 = "Must not contain NULLS for required fields";
    // have to initialize these two to some paths in hdfs

    String edtChkRptDtl = "/user/hduser/output6/detail" + inputKey + ".csv";
    String edtChkRptSmry = "/user/hduser/output6/summary" + inputKey + ".csv";
            ../

            List<String> errSmry = new ArrayList<String>();
    Map<String, String> loc = new TreeMap<String, String>();

    if(Strings.isNullOrEmpty(user.getPROJECT_NAME())) {
        loc.put("test", "PROJECT_NAME ");
        errSmry.add("_fail");
    } else if(Strings.isNullOrEmpty(user.getRESEARCH_CODE())) {
        loc.put("test", "RESEARCH_CODE ");
        errSmry.add("_fail");
    } else if(Strings.isNullOrEmpty(user.getFACILITY_CODE())) {
        loc.put("test", "FACILITY_CODE ");
        errSmry.add("_fail");
    } else if(Strings.isNullOrEmpty(user.getPROJECT_CODE())) {
        loc.put("test", "PROJECT_CODE ");
        errSmry.add("_fail");
    } else if(Strings.isNullOrEmpty(user.getINVESTIGATOR())) {
        loc.put("test", "INVESTIGATOR ");
        errSmry.add("_fail");
    } else if(Strings.isNullOrEmpty(user.getPATIENT_NUMBER())) {
        loc.put("test", "PATIENT_NUMBER ");
        errSmry.add("_fail");
    } else if(Strings.isNullOrEmpty(user.getSAMPLE_COLLECTION_DATE())) {
        loc.put("test", "SAMPLE_COLLECTION_DATE ");
        errSmry.add("_fail");
    } else if(Strings.isNullOrEmpty(user.getGENE_NAME())) {
        loc.put("test", "GENE_NAME ");
        errSmry.add("_fail");
    } else if(Strings.isNullOrEmpty(user.getSTRAND())) {
        loc.put("test", "STRAND ");
        errSmry.add("_fail");
    } else if(Strings.isNullOrEmpty(user.getASSAY_PLATFORM())) {
        loc.put("test", "ASSAY_PLATFORM ");
        errSmry.add("_fail");
    } else if(Strings.isNullOrEmpty(user.getSOFTWARE_NAME())) {
        loc.put("test", "SOFTWARE_NAME ");
        errSmry.add("_fail");
    } else if(Strings.isNullOrEmpty(user.getTEST_DATE())) {
        loc.put("test", "TEST_DATE ");
        errSmry.add("_fail");
    } else if(Strings.isNullOrEmpty(user.getPLATE_POSITION())) {
        loc.put("test", "PLATE_POSITION ");
        errSmry.add("_fail");
    } else if(Strings.isNullOrEmpty(user.getPLATE_ID())) {
        loc.put("test", "PLATE_ID ");
        errSmry.add("_fail");
    } else if(Strings.isNullOrEmpty(user.getOPERATOR())) {
        loc.put("test", "OPERATOR ");
        errSmry.add("_fail");
    } else if(Strings.isNullOrEmpty(user.getGENOTYPE())) {
        loc.put("test", "GENOTYPE ");
        errSmry.add("_fail");
    } else if(Strings.isNullOrEmpty(user.getSTAGE())) {
        loc.put("test", "STAGE ");
        errSmry.add("_fail");
    } else if(Strings.isNullOrEmpty(user.getLAB())) {
        loc.put("test", "LAB ");
        errSmry.add("_fail");
    }

    String customNullMsg = "Required Genotype column(s)";
    List<String> error = new ArrayList<String>();
    String message = null;

    if(!loc.isEmpty()) {
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : loc.entrySet()) {
        message = "line:" + entry.getKey() + " column:" + entry.getValue() + " " + f1;
        error.add(message);
        }
    } else {
        message = "_pass";
        error.add(message);
    }

    int cnt = 0;
    if(!errSmry.isEmpty()) {

        // not able to understand this. Are we trying to get the occurances
        // if the last key that contains _fail
        for (String key : errSmry) {
        if(key.contains("_fail")) {
            cnt = Collections.frequency(errSmry, key);
            // ******************** Nikhil added this
            break;
        }
        }

        if(cnt > 0) {
        writeCsvFileSmry(edtChkRptSmry, customNullMsg, p1, "failed", Integer.toString(cnt));
        } else {
        writeCsvFileSmry(edtChkRptSmry, customNullMsg, p1, "passed", "0");
        }

    } else {
        writeCsvFileSmry(edtChkRptSmry, customNullMsg, p1, "passed", "0");
    }

    // loop the list and write out items to the error report file
    if(!error.isEmpty()) {
        for (String s : error) {
        //System.out.println(s);
        if(s.contains("_fail")) {
            String updatedFailmsg = s.replace("_fail", "");
            writeCsvFileDtl(edtChkRptDtl, "genotype", updatedFailmsg, "failed");
        }
        if(s.contains("_pass")) {
            writeCsvFileDtl(edtChkRptDtl, "genotype", p1, "passed");
        }
        }
    } else {
        writeCsvFileDtl(edtChkRptDtl, "genotype", p1, "passed");
    }
    // end loop
   }

 private void writeCsvFileDtl(String edtChkRptDtl, String col1, String col2, String col3) {
    try {
        if(conf == null) {
            conf = new Configuration();
        }
        FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(conf);

        Path path = new Path(edtChkRptDtl);
        if (!fs.exists(path)) {
            FSDataOutputStream out = fs.create(path);
            out.writeChars(col1);
            out.writeChar(',');
            out.writeChars(col2);
            out.writeChar(',');
            out.writeChars(col3);
            out.writeChar('\n');
            out.flush();
            out.close();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void writeCsvFileSmry(String edtChkRptSmry, String col1, String col2, String col3, String col4) {
    try {


        if(conf == null) {
            conf = new Configuration();
        }
        FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(conf);

        Path path = new Path(edtChkRptSmry);
        if (!fs.exists(path)) {
            FSDataOutputStream out = fs.create(path);
            out.writeChars(col1);
            out.writeChar(',');
            out.writeChars(col2);
            out.writeChar(',');
            out.writeChars(col3);
            out.writeChar(',');
            out.writeChars(col4);
            out.writeChar('\n');
            out.flush();
            out.close();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Here is my driver class

```
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configured;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.Tool;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner;

public class GWASMapReduce extends Configured implements Tool{

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
    ToolRunner.run(configuration, new GWASMapReduce(), args);
}

@Override
public int run(String[] arg0) throws Exception {

    JobConf conf = new JobConf(new Configuration());
    conf.setInputFormat(GWASInputFormat.class);
    conf.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    conf.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);
    conf.setJarByClass(GWASMapReduce.class);
    conf.setMapperClass(GWASMapper.class);
    conf.setNumReduceTasks(0);
    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(conf, new Path(arg0[0]));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(conf, new Path(arg0[1]));
    JobClient.runJob(conf);
    return 0;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There will probably be only one Mapper task, and ten invocations of it's `map` method. If you wish to write out one file per Mapper, you should do so in its `configure` method. If you wish to write out one file per input record, you should so in its `map` method.

Edit: The above turned out to be unrelated to the problem. The issue is that in GWASInputFormat, you do not set the key in the next method, so your map input key is always the same. Simply add `key.set(lineKey.get());` to the `next` method, and it should work.

Comment: The Mapper gets only one input record. So I do not have to do anything special in the mapper to generate one file per record right ?

Comment: Are you sure that the Mapper only gets one input record? This is not the way MapReduce normally works and you would have to be specifically doing this in the GWASInputFormat. You do NOT get one map task per input record; you get one map task per input split. Each input split can have many records. You are correct, however, in saying that if you want one file per record, you can do it directly in the `map` method. If you are doing this and still only seeing one file, make sure you are using a different file name and not overwriting previous output.

Comment: Yes, I have updated the question with GWASInputFormat. So each split contains only one record. Also I am using a different file name in my mapper too. I put my mapper class also in the question.

Comment: Your GWASInputFormat does not do what you think it does. There is a difference between a "split" and a "record". Because you extend from FileInputFormat, you get its default splitting behavior, which is to split on HDFS block boundaries. You will have only 1 split, with 10 records. You will have one mapper that will receive all 10 records.

Also, your posted code omits the file creation. Please include what you have attempted there.

Comment: Hmm the way I formatted is that the map receives GWASGenotypeBean which is an object for a record. So I am not quite sure when you say that I am sending all the 10 records to the mapper. Because if you see my map function it takes <LongWritable, GWASGenotypeBean>. I have added the code for file creation. Please correct me if I am wrong

Comment: Each time the map method is called, it will get only 1 record, but each instance of the GWASMapper will have its map method called 10 times, with different records passed in. But anyway, this does not seem to be the problem. The issue is that in GWASInputFormat, you do not set the key in the next method, so your map input key is always the same. Simply add `key.set(lineKey.get());` to the `next` method, and it should work.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19117/discussion-between-user1707141-and-joe-k)